# Series/integral of function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

I've tried to resolve an exercise and at some point I have to compare the integral :
$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $

with the series : 
$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $

in order to figure out if the integral converges or not.

In the exercise, we have $f(x) \geq 0$, and it's explained that **as** $f(x) \geq 0$ the series converges $\iff$ the integral converges.

But actually, I can't figure out why $f$ must have a constant sign, because maybe what I'm gonna written is absolutely wrong, but I want to say :
$ \int_{0}^{n\pi} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $, and so : $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{n\pi} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =  \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $

whatever the sign of $f$, and then both the series and the integral have the same nature (convergent of divergent).

So, where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sin{2x}$. Then $\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \sin{2x} \, dx = 0$, but $\int_0^{\infty} \sin{2x} \, dx $ does not converge.

The point is that the partial sums only capture the behaviour of $\int_0^M f $ for certain values of $M$. It's the same as $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos{x}$: if you just look at the values $2k\pi$, it looks like it converges to $1$, but we know this is not true.

You have (integral converges) $\implies $ (partial sums converge), but not the other direction.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't manage to find what's wrong in what i've written, where is the mistake...

Comment: You have assumed that $g(n) \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ ($n$ an integer) $\implies g(x) \to a$ as $x \to \infty$ ($x$ real). My example shows that this is not the case in general.

Comment: Yes thank you, after taking a little pause and re-thinking about it, it's okay ! Thank you !